# MoqHttpMessageHanlder.Respond to pass content as (mediatype, data) where "data" contains list as one of the entities

Tags: api, unit-testing, moq

We have an API that returns the below response and Unit Test for it need to be written

```
{
    "farmLabel": "US_50_Content",
    "farmNetworkOctets": [
        {
            "f5OctetsIn95": 222129831936,
            "aggOctetsIn95": 7226308689920,
            "period": "Daily"
        },
        {
            "f5OctetsIn95": 232228847616,
            "aggOctetsIn95": 7145860366336,
            "period": "Weekly"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
_moqHttpClient.When("https://moqapi/*/api/GeoId_FarmId_01")
      .Respond("application/json", "{'FarmLabel' : 'FarmLabelName', 'FarmNetworkOctets' : [{'F5OctetsIn95' : '222129831936', 'AggOctetsIn95' : '7226308689920', 'Period : 'Daily'}]}");


var sut = CallApi(); //Returns the above moq Response


Assert.IsNotNull(sut);
```

The above code returns false and the testCase fails

```
            _moqHttpClient.When("https://moqgridstatebaseuri/*/api/NetworkOctets/In/FarmLabel/P95/v2/GeoId_FarmLabelId_01")
.Respond("application/json", "{'FarmLabel' : 'FarmLabelName', 'FarmNetworkOctets' : []}");

var sut = await _gridstateManagerService.GetFarmLabelOctetsInAsync(Constants.FARMLABEL_NAME);

Assert.IsNotNull(sut);
```

The above code returns true and test case passes.

I believe there is some issue in the way "FarmNetworkOctets Object" is being passed the data.
Any help as to how to moq such api response would be helpful.